# Textarea: Size of a window with no border

Tags: textarea

How do you make a textarea with no border and takes up all of the space it can?

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is:

```
<style type="text/css">
textarea.test
{  
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border-color: Transparent;     
}
</style>
<textarea class="test"></textarea>
```

Comment: 100% takes up all of the space that it can.